# Android bluetooth message communication

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm currently developing an app that communicates through Bluetooth with a proprietary device.
By exploring the [Bluetooth Chat Example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat) I could get the communication to work flawlessly.
In this example, the whole writing/reading process goes as: 
https://goo.gl/photos/3CoSNbhRtyDNoV1F6

Now I want to create a writing/reading method from inside MyBluetoothClass (for checksum verification purposes). So it would be something like:
//See same link above//

But now the method executes everything but the writing and reading itself, what just happens after the method finish.
Could someone give me an advice on how to proceed? Below are the methods related to the new writing method.

```
    //Writing method called from the Activity
private String writeWithChksum(String msg) {
    write(msg);
    readCompleted.set(false);
    return processDeviceID();
}

//Get the device ID
private String processDeviceID() {
    Thread timeoutThread;
    int tries = 0;

    while(tries < 3) {
        tries++;
        System.out.println("Trying to get ID for the "+tries+" time.");

        waitingMessage.set(true);

        timeout.set(false);
        timeoutThread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(TIME_LIMIT);
                    timeout.set(true);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        };
        timeoutThread.start();

        while(waitingMessage.get() && !timeout.get()) {
            sleepThread(150);
        }

        timeoutThread.interrupt();
    }

    readCompleted.set(true);
    return deviceID;
}

//Handler used to deal with BT methods
private final Handler auxHandler = new Handler() {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        switch (msg.what) {
            case BluetoothSerial.MESSAGE_WRITE:
                byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the buffer
                String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);

                //THIS SHOULD APPEAR IN EXECUTION TIME WHILE THE INITIAL METHOD IS STILL RUNNING, NOT AFTER
                Log.d(TAG,"BLUETOOTH_HANDLER -->" + "Wrote: "+writeMessage);
                break;
            case BluetoothSerial.MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);

                //THIS AS WELL NEED TO APPEAR WHILE IN EXECUTION TIME
                Log.d(TAG,"BLUETOOTH_HANDLER -->" + "Read: "+readMessage);

                System.out.println("Gonna process the message");
                processMessage(readMessage);
                break;
        }
    }
};

//Standard writing method
public void write(String msg) {
    // Create temporary object
    ConnectedThread r;

    // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
    synchronized (this) {
        if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) return;
        r = mConnectedThread;
    }

    // Perform the write unsynchronized
    msg = ">"+msg+"<\r\n";
    byte[] send = msg.getBytes();
    r.write(send);
    msgNumber++;

    sleepThread(400);
}

public void write(byte[] buffer) {
    try {
        mmOutStream.write(buffer);

        // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
        mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                .sendToTarget();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
    }
}
```